# asp:menu : need to show sub-menu items when page is loaded with different style

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, submenu, aspmenu

```
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="RelativeSiteMapDataSource" StartFromCurrentNode="False"
    ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="CatalogSiteMap" />

<asp:Menu runat="server" ID="Navigator" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
    Orientation="Vertical" DataSourceID="RelativeSiteMapDataSource"   />
```

I have the above code in few ASPX pages.

What I want to be able to do is to show ALL the sub-menu items when page is loaded and there should be some sort of indenting to show hierarchy of menu items. The above code currently opens sub-menu when it's parent menu item is clicked (example, when I click on Products menu it shows it's sub-menu).

PS: It is not allowing to attach image as I am a new user.
But I have shown how I want menu to be displayed below, Please suggest.

Products

- Instock
- Out-of-Stock

Orders

- Purchase Orders
- Sales Orders

  - Back Orders
  - Invoiced Orders

Documents

- Purchase
- Invoice

**Update 1:** Currently with the above code, all menu items (and sub-menu items) are not shown when page is loaded. So I would first like to tweak the asp:menu to get all menu items and then I would like to apply the CSS (which is with asp:menu) to show the way mentioned above.

**Update 2:** This is what the menu looks like (taken from view source).

Products
        Orders
        Documents

Comment: This is a client-side problem, so show the actual HTML output, then CSS can likely take care of this by using a background image. Your server-side code doesn't help solve this.

Comment: I have updated the question to give more clarity.

Comment: Once again, show your HTML, not your .net code.

Comment: Here is the HTML output from viewsource. <ul class="Menu">
  <li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://prodxeon/products.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Products">Products</a></li>
  <li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://prodxeon/orders.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Orders">Orders</a></li>
  <li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://prodxeon/documents.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Documents">Documents</a></li>
 </ul>

Answer (score 1):

In asp:menu source code (aspx page) Just by setting two properties namely: `RenderingMode ="List"` and `StaticDisplayLevels="3"` , I created the same menu that you want to show on page load. Now you can apply css on this as all these just simple bullet lists.

Comment: I don't see renderingmode in the asp:menu properties. Also how do I specify CSS and in my case I want sub-menu items to have bulletted and shifted to the right ? thanks.

Comment: StaticDisplayLevels="3" does display the child menu items but only after I click on the parent menu item. How can I show the entire menu (including sub-menus, sub-sub-menus, sub-sub-sub-menus?)

Comment: property names in asp.net are case sensitive. You are typing in lower case. Also check the property names properly by this way. Open properties window. Then click on small button showing a-z image on it. It will display the property in sorted order. Now the first property listed With Letter "R" is RenderingMode. Just set its value as list. After this it should work fine. Also It will display them already shifted to right in case of submenu

Comment: The way I checked for property is by putting spacebar and it shows all available properties. for example I type <asp:Menu and then press spacebar and I don't RenderingMode in that list. Please let me know.

Comment: StaticDisplayLevels="3" does display the child menu items but only after I click on the parent menu item. Do you know why it could be? Also you said in the above reply that display will get shifted in case of submenu? I am not clear on that.

Comment: Sorry, My Mistake. The RenderingMode property is available only in .Net 4.0. May be you are using a lower version. But you can create similar menu using only CSS and ULs( use nested lists for your menu). This may not be very laborious work and you will have full control over your menu too.

Comment: I am not using ASP.NET 4.0. Are there any ways to use within asp.net 2.0 with asp:menu itself? Please suggest with any examples etc.